# Can't delete dangling k8s load balancer due to http target proxy that doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I'm trying to delete the forwarding rule, target proxy, url map and backend services that belong to an extinct k8s ingress.

I successfully delete the forwarding rule and target proxy but then when I go to delete the url-map I get this:

```
 gcloud compute url-maps delete k8s-um-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0 --quiet
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.url-maps.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - The url_map resource 'projects/project-id/global/urlMaps/k8s-um-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0' is already being used by 'projects/project-id/global/targetHttpProxies/k8s-tp-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0
```

`k8s-tp-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0` is not the name of the target proxy it belonged to, but I go ahead and try and delete it anyways and get:

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies delete k8s-tp-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0 --quiet
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.target-https-proxies.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/project-id/global/targetHttpsProxies/k8s-tp-prism-feature-password-workflow-unit-tests-prism-ingres0' was not found
```

Comment: Could you confirm if you are able to delete the Load Balancer resource from the UI?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to forcefully delete the LoadBalancer you can do something like

```
kubectl edit svc YOUR_SERVICE
```

And look for this line:

```
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
```

and remove it from the yaml, save and quit and it should remove the LoadBalancer

Comment: How can we see that the service is being finalized or attempting to be finalized? Is there anywhere we might look to gather that this is what we need to do?

Comment: Yeah it is possible, these load balancers are mapped to actual load balancers depending on the cloud provider. For example in AWS, go to EC2 screen and then click LoadBalancers on the Sidebar, you'll be able to see which LoadBalancers are pending from that list, same is true for GKE and AKS